# Visual Studio Xamarin not building Android packaged_resources is missing

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I am using Visual Studio Community Edition 2015 with Xamarin and I can't run my Android project successfully.  It doesn't look like the android objects are getting created in the \obj folder.  An error gets thrown that the packaged_resources doesn't exist.  I notice that alot of other files don't get created in the \obj folder.  The Emulator starts fine, but my project is not loaded in the Emulator.  So I wonder, does Xamarin not work with Visual Studio Community Edition?  I don't see any minimum requirements on the Xamarin website.

Comment: Can you double check that you do not have any illegal characters in your `Resource` file names? This sounds very familiar to: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/168172/#Comment_168172

Comment: Yeah, I checked that and they are just standard characters in the file names.

Comment: Here is the diagnostic build output... gist.github.com/anonymous/b9c4b4af90777dd2916f

Comment: I'd recommend 2 things:

1. Go through your `Resources` and slowly remove them from your project (Right Click -> Exclude from project). Do this until your application compiles again. Then you will have an idea which resource is causing this.

2. Change your build-tools as you're using a preview 24.0 version. Add a similar statement to your .csproj of your Droid project `<AndroidSdkBuildToolsVersion>23.0.3</AndroidSdkBuildToolsVersion>`

Comment: Is there a specific block this should go under?

Comment: I'd place it along your other Android-esq properties.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/under_the_hood/build_process/#Packaging_Properties

Comment: That was the issue!  Its that Build Tools version!

Comment: Can you place your comment as an answer below and then I will check mark it as an answer?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a preview Android SDK `build-tools` version(preview 24) that we might not support quite yet :)

You can change your build-tools version via the `$(AndroidSdkBuildToolsVersion)` property.

i.e.

`<AndroidSdkBuildToolsVersion>23.0.3</AndroidSdkBuildToolsVersion>`

Further documentation

`https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/under_the_hood/build_process/#Packaging_Properties`

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin is totally compatible with Visual Studio Community edition, so this may be indicative of a different problem. I can think of a few possible causes, but to confirm anything I would need to see a copy of the build log, preferably the full diagnostic variant.

If you are unsure on how to obtain this, there is a guide here: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting/troubleshooting/#Diagnostic_MSBuild_Output

Thanks!

Comment: How do I get you that?  I can't paste it into the logs, it is too long.